# Flutter - Parameter Type for a Method

Tags: flutter, function, parameters

I am working a FLUTTER project and need to write a method (or maybe a function). One of the parameters in the method needs to be an expression like:

`PlayList videos = videoList[index] as PlayList`

Is it possible? If so what type should I should use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- [typedef](https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#typedefs) can set the data type, method parameters

```
typedef ProcessCallback = PlayList Function();
```

- set as method parameter

```
void foo(ProcessCallback callback) {
   /// result type is PlayList
   var result =  callback.call();
}
```

- when calling the foo method

```
 ProcessCallback callback = () => videoList[index] as PlayList;
 foo(callback);
```

- Before actually running the callback.call() method, it is just a data type:
  Closure: () => PlayList
- .call() can also be replaced with ();